# Derivative of Exponential map on manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, proof-verification, proof-writing, riemannian-geometry

I'm trying to compute the derivative of the map $f:\Sigma\times [0,\delta)\to M$ given by
$$f(p,t)=\exp_p tN(p),$$
in $X\in T_p\Sigma$, where $(M^n,g)$ is a Riemannian manifold, $\Sigma\subset M$ a immersed hypersurface and $N$ is a unit normal vector field along to $\Sigma$. If $X\in T_p \Sigma$ then I think something like that

\begin{align}
df_{(p,t)}X &=\frac{d}{ds}\bigg|_{s=0}f\circ c(s)
\end{align}

where $c$ is a differentiable curve in $\Sigma\times [0,\delta)$ with $c(0)=(p,t)$ and $c'(0)=X$. Taking $c(s)=(\exp_p sX,t)=(c_1(s),t)$, we have

\begin{align}
df_{(p,t)}X &=\frac{d}{ds}\bigg|_{s=0}\exp_{c_1(s)}tN(c_1(s))\\
&\overset{*}{=}d(\exp_{c_1(s)})_{tN(c_1(s))}\nabla_{c'(s)}N(c(s))\bigg|_{s=0}\\
&= d(\exp_p)_{tN(p)}\nabla_X N(p).
\end{align}

In fact, I would like know if the equality (*) make sense because in this calculation when I derive $\exp_{c_1(s)}tN(c_1(s))$ the curve $c_1$ is varying.

---

NOTE: The original problem is decompose the pullback metric. I posted [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/243924/decomposition-of-pullback-metric)
but I don't understand the solution suggested. So, I tried to do something different.